# Why does Ruby's symbol to proc invoke the count method instead of the :count Hash key?

Tags: ruby

Given this irb session:

```
[2.0.0p195]> arr = [{count: 5}, {count: 6}, {count: 7}]
=> [{:count=>5}, {:count=>6}, {:count=>7}]
[2.0.0p195]> arr.collect(&:count)
=> [1, 1, 1]
```

wat

```
[2.0.0p195]> arr.collect(&:count).reduce(:+)
=> 3
[2.0.0p195]> arr.collect {|e| e[:count]}.reduce(:+)
=> 18
```

Can I exclude methods on Hash when `collect`ing or is using a block the only way around this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

& means call `#to_proc` on its argument, and the [Symbol class implements this](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Symbol.html#method-i-to_proc) by creating a Proc that calls the method name based on the symbol - so `&:symbol` means "Call the #symbol method on the passed in object". Essentially, what you've got is the equivalent of this:

```
arr.collect{|obj| obj.send(:count)}
```

Since Hash won't respond to the "count" method at all to get the value of the :count key - that is, `Hash#count` is not the same as `Hash#[](:count)`, (though [OpenStruct](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html) does do this for you), you're stuck with the block method.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative is to create a lambda, useful if you are writing the same block many times:

```
fetch_count = -> x{x[:count]}
arr.collect(&fetch_count) #=> [5, 6, 7]

# If hash only has one value as in example:
arr.collect(&values).flatten #=> [5, 6, 7]
```

Comment: *+1* for `lambda`. You can write `arr.collect(&values).flatten` as `arr.flat_map(&values)`

Answer (score 2):

The implementation of calling & on a symbol is as follows (more or less):

```
class Symbol
  def to_proc
    Proc.new { |obj| obj.send self }
  end
end
```

You can see that all it is doing (when combined with a `#map`) is calling the method corresponding to the provided symbol on each member of the enumerable.

You could fix this if you really wanted by using `OpenStruct`s instead of hashes, they have method-style access of elements:

```
[{test: 1}].map { |h| OpenStruct.new(h) }.map &:test                                          
#=> [1]
```

Or invent an operator that does what you want for hash access in addition to `&`, I may revisit this challenge if I have a spare moment later!

**EDIT: I have returned**

This is hacky but you could monkey-patch symbol to provide the functionality that you wish for by augmenting with unary `~`:

```
# Patch
class Symbol
  def ~@
    ->(obj){ obj[self] }
  end
end

# Example usage:
[{count: 5}, {count: 6}, {count: 7}].map &~:count                                             
#=> [5, 6, 7]
```

If a free-for-all language such as Ruby doesn't have a feature that you wish for, you can always build it in :-)

Disclaimer: This is probably a terrible idea.